# How to avoid duplicacy because of lag b/w master/slave?

Tags: mysql, database, lag

We have a master DB and slave DB. Master DB is used to serve the live traffic(read/writes) and slave is used to server the offline/background processes.
There is generally a lag b/w master and slave for 15 to 20 mins.

There is a process running every minute checks if some data(say base_condition) is not there on slave  , update that base_condition in master and send the email. But due to the lag b/w master and slave this process  sends the email again as it base condition is not updated on slave due to lag. I am not sure what can be best solution for the-bottom-up
same.

Some solution I can think of

1. Use the master only instead of slave
2. Keep the updates base condition also as temporary data on slave  and check for that too.

Second looks like a hack or tem solution to me. I will go first one but it defeats my rule where master should be used for live traffic. So down the line
it will add more processes like this. Is there any better solution like this ?

Comment: This will probably depend on your actual condition and you may need to add some details about it (and your intended purpose of the slave server, e.g. "just for reporting"). It looks time dependent (e.g. it was true 20 minutes before on the live server, but not 20 minutes later on the slave). You may be able to adjust the test to run 20 minutes later (or, better, not rely on the current time), but you might also argue that a condition that has to be fulfilled at a specific time is more a "live data" thing, especially if it updates the live data based on this.

Comment: *"There is generally a lag b/w master and slave for 15 to 20 mins."*  Option 3 seems like it would be "find and fix this problem."  Such a lag is certainly not typical. On a well-behaved system it should be measured in milliseconds.